# Create Unix script to delete records in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle11g

We have a UNIX box hosting an Oracle DB. We need to delete records on a daily basis from a table in this DB. We are setting up a scheduled job outside of Oracle that will run a script daily to do this.

Could you please help me create a .sh script file to do the same?  I have the username/pwd for the DB.

The query is: `DELETE FROM AUDIT_LOG WHERE EVENT_DATE <= SYSTIMESTAMP - 1;`

Comment: Why not an Oracle Job? You could do the same thing without shell scripts. Is this an option?

Comment: Quite honestly, I prefer using Oracle Job.  However, company policy for scheduled jobs is to use a separate scheduler that runs scripts and tracks them, etc.  I have never written a script for Oracle related stuff and am not well-versed in UNIX scripting.

Answer (score 1):

In KORN shell you can do this as below:

```
#!/bin/ksh

`sqlplus "<schema_name>/<password>" << EOF

set feedback off
set heading off

DELETE FROM AUDIT_LOG WHERE EVENT_DATE <= SYSTIMESTAMP - 1;

exit;
EOF`
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will give this a try.